# vscode code action method position

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

When using a code action (light bulb) in Visual Studio Code to add a method  to a class, the method is always added at the very top. Is there a way to add it under the constructor and/or under the class members? Specifically in a TypeScript file.

[screenshot of code action light bulb](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XqNts.jpg)

Comment: Sorry, but I don't know this behavior at all. Do you use any plug-in's that provide this "light bulb"?

Comment: I added a screenshot of the code action light bulb.